# Wrapping div not covering 100% height of body

Tags: css

I have a #wrapper div that has a background image. I want to make this cover 100% of my page.

I've read to do this you must set the height of the `html` and `body` to 100% and I have my css set up as such:

```
HTML, BODY {
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('myimage.png');
}
```

However, the wrapper div just takes up 100% of the area visible on the browser - the background image disappears if you scroll down.

Would someone know how to set this up properly or what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Makes your background ignore scrolling.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_js_background-attachment